# How to load additional beans and configuration files in the WebApplicationContext of XML and Java configured Spring web apps?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-3.0, applicationcontext

I'm building a library that listens to the initialization of the Root Web Application Context for Spring web-apps by implementing the `ServletContextListener` interface. I'm using the servlet API 3.0.
The library then loads into the web application context some necessary config files (mainly controller beans and spring security configuration XML files) before refreshing the context.

```
@WebListener
public class CustomListener implements ServletContextListener {

     @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        this.servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
        WebApplicationContext wac = null;

        try {
            wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.servletContext);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
            logger.error("Could not retrieve the WebApplicationContext", ise);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Encountered an error while trying to retrieve the WebApplicationContext", e);
        }

        if (wac != null && wac instanceof XmlWebApplicationContext) {
            wac.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(CustomProperties.getInstance());

            //configLocations will contain = ["classpath*:securityContext.xml", "classpath*:spring-controllers.xml"]
            String[] configLocations = this.getCustomConfigFilesLocations();

            wac.setConfigLocations(configLocations);
            wac.refresh();

            Optional<String> servletName = ContextInitializerUtils.getServletNameForClass(this.servletContext,
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.class);
            if (!servletName.isPresent()) {
                DispatcherServlet serv = new DispatcherServlet(wac);
                ServletRegistration.Dynamic servletDynamic = servletContext.addServlet("spring", servlet);
                servletDynamic.addMapping("/customapi/*");
                servletDynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            }
            else {
                this.servletContex.servletContext.getServletRegistrations().get(servletName).addMapping("/customapi/*");
            }
        }
        else {
            //What should I do in this case ?
        }

    }
}
```

This works great, I can access my controllers from the app that uses my library, with the Spring Security configuration I declared in my file ... but ONLY for applications that have XML-based configuration and that have declared a `ContextLoaderListener` in their web.xml.

I want to be able to do the same with Spring applications that have a Java-based configuration, and eventually Spring Boot applications.
With Java configured Spring apps, I tried doing something quite similar in the same class, with `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` but I encountered 2 problems :

1. `@WebListener` classes seem to be loaded before the initialization of the Root Web Application Context for this kind of apps. Hence `getRequiredWebApplicationContext` always returns an exception.
   `@WebListener` is called on a `ApplicationContextFacade` event, instead of a `StandardContext$NoPluggabilityServletContext` event that holds the root web context.
2. I deleted the `@WebListener` annotation and tried loading the listener programmatically by implementing the `WebApplicationInitializer` interface and adding a listener to the `servletContext` in the `onStartup` method.
   It seemed to work, I have access to the Root Web Application Context through the `StandardContext$NoPluggabilityServletContext` event but when I try to use the Servlet 3.0 API for eg. `getFilterRegistrations` `addServlet` ... 
   I get this exception :

`addServlet java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Section 4.4 of the Servlet 3.0 specification does not permit this method to be called from a ServletContextListener that was not defined in web.xml`

```
WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.servletContext);

if (wac != null && wac instanceof ConfigurableWebApplicationContext) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServletConfiguration = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherServletConfiguration.setParent(wac);
    dispatcherServletConfiguration.register(CustomApiConfiguration.class);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcherServlet = servletContext.addServlet("spring", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServletConfiguration));
    dispatcherServlet.addMapping("/customapi/*");
    dispatcherServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
}


@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath*:securityContext.xml", "classpath*:spring-controllers.xml" })
public class CustomApiConfiguration {


}
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I achieve the same for Java-configured Spring apps ? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do ? Making it as transparent as possible to the application using my library.

Comment: XML configuration for Spring is an old idea that has been superseded by annotations.   Sounds like you are using an old version of Spring. We're up to 5.x now.  You might consider rethinking this problem and upgrading.  It could be that refactoring to REST microservices is in order.

Comment: The reality is quite different I'm afraid. I wish I can upgrade the version of Spring we are using to the latest one, but we have requirements to be met for the library but also for the apps that are still using Spring 4.2.x and 4.3.x. Plus, we have technical platforms that enforce and define BOMs containing the versions of all dependencies we can and should use.

Comment: That's the excuse that everyone who falls behind uses.  This will only come to grief.  The longer you wait the more painful achieving currency will become.  Good luck.